# Specific pattern strings from List in python 3

Tags: python, regex

Requirement:using regex want to fetch only specific strings i.e. string betwee "-" and "*" symbols from input list. Below is the code snippet

```
    ZTon = ['one-- and preferably only one --obvious', " Hello World", 'Now is better than never.', 'Although never is often better than *right* now.']
ZTon = [ line.strip() for line in ZTon]
print (ZTon)
r = re.compile(".^--")
portion = list(filter(r.match, ZTon)) # Read Note
print (portion)
```

Expected response:

```
['and preferably only one','right']
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Please share the code you tried to fetch strings, not the usage of `strip()`.

Comment: ZTon = ['one-- and preferably only one --obvious', " Hello World", 'Now is better than never.', 'Although never is often better than *right* now.']
ZTon = [ line.strip() for line in ZTon]
print (ZTon)
r = re.compile(".^--")
portion = list(filter(r.match, ZTon)) # Read Note
print (portion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex

```
import re
ZTon = ['one-- and preferably only one --obvious', " Hello World", 'Now is better than never.', 'Although never is often better than *right* now.']
pattern=r'(--|\*)(.*)\1'
l=[]
for line in ZTon:
    s=re.search(pattern,line)
    if s:l.append(s.group(2).strip())
print (l)
# ['and preferably only one', 'right']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

ZTon = ['one-- and preferably only one --obvious', " Hello World", 'Now is better than never.', 'Although never is often better than *right* now.']

def gen(lst):
    for s in lst:
        s = ''.join(i.strip() for g in re.findall(r'(?:-([^-]+)-)|(?:\*([^*]+)\*)', s) for i in g)
        if s:
            yield s

print(list(gen(ZTon)))
```

Prints:

```
['and preferably only one', 'right']
```